Anchor deploy failed from "insufficient funds"
I tried deploying a program on mainnet using anchor deploy and ran into a failed deployment due to "Account has insufficient funds for spend (6.62478552 SOL) + fee (0.004725 SOL)" even though the fee-payer account had ~10 SOL.
I went to recover the lamports from the program buffers however, running solana program show --buffers returns no buffer accounts, and trying solana program close --buffers doesn't work.
I then checked the explorer to see what happened in the transaction and found that the 10 SOL was transferred to a System Program account to execute the transaction. That account seems to be holding the SOL I used for the transaction.
All transactions in the deployment executed successfully except one which caused the error.
The images here further illustrate the problem.
Here is also the transaction signature on mainnet: 2kum8APtBMNdcgkNDoWAPiHXSzLAjEQMjeDYmX7Q3uD45t6dUJ5bUmeBjndGVweb9zmEepMtWPKNzQH8hEB6uwa4
I've deployed on devnet and localnet with no problem and I've been able to recover SOL from failed deployments.
My question is how can I recover the SOL if there appears to be no available buffers and how can I prevent this error from occurring if I want to retry the deployment?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

the tx you provided seems to be a regular sol transfer tx, could you also provide the other tx hashes for the failed deploys.

hello, thank you for the response. that was the only failed deploy in that transaction.  the account that initiated the deploy began showing weird behavior (possibly compromised?). the account was turned into a token account and all the SOL was drained. I had never used the account on mainnet before so im not sure how it happened from running a deploy

Your 10 SOL is transfered to certain address, which is not System Program account.
I'm wondering if you have been hacked.

hey @steven-hocking, thanks for looking into that. I noticed that as well and believe that may have been the case. I just found it strange how that could've happened considering that i never used that address on mainnet or anywhere else outside of local development

Recently, I've been getting a lot of hacking attempts through social communities and online. They ask me to install some software or interact with a website. Of course, I didn't click on anything and didn't install anything.
